# Explode and insert values to multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql, explode

I need to explode a string, first by line, and then by # and insert to mysql.

Like i have a string

```
Shahbaz#is my name
Singh#is my caste
```

I want the script to explode the string first by a new line, insert `Shahbaz` into the `word` column and `is my name` into the `note` column in mysql and same with `Singh` and `is my caste`.

```
include("connect.php");
$counter = 0;
$counters = 0;
$string = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['words']);
$arr = explode(" ", $string);
mysql_query("SET charset utf8");
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT `word` FROM unicode WHERE word IN ('".implode("', '", $arr) . "')") or die (mysql_error());
$dupes = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    $dupes[] = $r['word'];
}
$newwords = array_diff($arr, $dupes);
if(count($newwords)) {
     $sqli = mysql_query("INSERT INTO unicode (word) VALUES ('" . implode("'),('", $newwords) . "')") or die (mysql_error());
}
```

In this script, it inserts each word, but doesnt insert the note column. It separates the words by a space. I want it to separate it by a new line and then insert the text after `#` to the `note` column...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am struggling to understand what you are doing.  What is the table `unicode`?  Why doesn't your code mention the `note` column anywhere?

Comment: actually in this code, it just enters the value to the word column, i want it to add a new value to the `note` column too...

Comment: Can you provide example data of what `unicode` looks like before and what you want it to look like after?